# Firefox is showing the wrong arrow characters

Tags: macos, firefox, fonts

I see up arrows in Math texts where the arrow should go from left to right, and down arrows for arrows that should go from right to left. If I cut and paste to another text editor, I get the proper right and left arrows.  Example page where I am experiencing this: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/

Why is Firefox showing the wrong characters, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you give us a link to a page where you experience this? It would help diagnosing exactly which characters are involved and why they may be interpreted wrong. As a quick test, I am going to place the following HTML entities in my comment in order: left arrow, right arrow, up arrow, down arrow. Let me know what you see: ← , → , ↑ , ↓

Comment: The display for your 4 arrows is perfect. The page I was looking at was: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick report of `http://plato.stanford.edu/.../logic-higher-order`:

- **Encoding**: `Unicode (UTF-8)`; <sup>Good!</sup>
- **Markup**: Valid `XHTML 1.0 Transitional`; <sup>Good!</sup>
- **Font Family**: `serif` <sup>Good!</sup>

I see no problems with the page, and based on the above details, I assume your browser is using a `serif` font that does not support some `UTF-8` characters, especially the left and right arrow.

Since you are using Firefox, you can change this by going to:

- **Options > Content > Fonts & Colors > Advanced**

and changing the the settings like so:

- **Fonts for**: `Western`
- **Serif**: `<a serif font with Unicode support>`
- **Character Encoding > Default**: `Unicode (UTF-8)`

If you are not sure of which [Unicode font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces#Unicode_fonts) to use, I recommend [DejaVu Serif](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page).

---

**Note**: My [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/428594/arrows-in-firefox#comment492414_428594) above is computed from the following list of fonts:

```
Arial, Liberation Sans, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif
```

This is different than just `serif`. A browser will look for each font in the list until it finds one installed on your system. Your browser is being instructed to use different fonts in each case, which explains why you may be able to see the arrow characters here but not on the other page.

Comment: Thanks, it will works, I have tried with Lucida Grande, and the arrows show up correctly. However, I now need to find a font I like. I was using Times before, and I got used to it, Lucida Grande is not quite as nice for me.

Comment: Times New Roman seems to be very close to Times, but with the correct arrows. Phew!!! For reference, I'm on a Mac. Thanks!

Comment: That's great! No problem. :)

Comment: @Frank If this problem is solved, you can **accept** the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. This lets the community know to move on to other, unsolved problems.  (Plus, we both get reputation points `;)` ) Welcome to Super User!